# Search bar in a TableViewController with Core Data

Tags: swift, search, swift3, uisearchbar

I am making a TableViewController with Core Data. In fact, the users can add new items to the Table View and these items are saved in Core Data.The view will display a contacts list.
Everything has worked fine but I couldn't get a search bar to work. I tried a lot but I am new to swift and this is my first app. Please tell me what should I add to my code?

```swift
class ContactsViewController: UITableViewController {

    @IBOutlet var searchBar: UISearchBar!
    var contacts: [NSManagedObject] = []



    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        fetch()
        tableView.reloadData()

    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    //MARK: - Data Source

    func fetch() {
        guard let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as? AppDelegate else { return }
        let managedObjectContext = appDelegate.persistentContainer.viewContext
        let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest<NSFetchRequestResult>(entityName:"Contact")
        do {
            contacts = try managedObjectContext.fetch(fetchRequest) as! [NSManagedObject]
        } catch let error as NSError {
            print("Could not fetch. \(error)")
        }
    }

    func save(name: String, phoneNumber: String, dataUltimei: String) {
        guard let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as? AppDelegate else { return }
        let managedObjectContext = appDelegate.persistentContainer.viewContext
        guard let entity = NSEntityDescription.entity(forEntityName:"Contact", in: managedObjectContext) else { return }
        let contact = NSManagedObject(entity: entity, insertInto: managedObjectContext)
        contact.setValue(name, forKey: "name")
        contact.setValue(phoneNumber, forKey: "phoneNumber")
        contact.setValue(dataUltimei, forKey: "dataUltimei")
        do {
            try managedObjectContext.save()
            self.contacts.append(contact)
        } catch let error as NSError {
            print("Couldn't save. \(error)")
        }
    }

    func update(indexPath: IndexPath, name:String, phoneNumber: String, dataUltimei: String) {
        guard let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as? AppDelegate else { return }
        let managedObjectContext = appDelegate.persistentContainer.viewContext
        let contact = contacts[indexPath.row]
        contact.setValue(name, forKey:"name")
        contact.setValue(phoneNumber, forKey: "phoneNumber")
        contact.setValue(dataUltimei, forKey: "dataUltimei")
        do {
            try managedObjectContext.save()
            contacts[indexPath.row] = contact
        } catch let error as NSError {
            print("Couldn't update. \(error)")
        }
    }

    func delete(_ contact: NSManagedObject, at indexPath: IndexPath) {
        guard let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as? AppDelegate else { return }
        let managedObjectContext = appDelegate.persistentContainer.viewContext
        managedObjectContext.delete(contact)
        contacts.remove(at: indexPath.row)
    }

    override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {


        return contacts.count

    }




    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {


        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "ContactCell", for: indexPath)

        var contact = contacts[indexPath.row]

        if isSearching {

            contact = contacts[indexPath.row]

        }
        else {

            contact = contacts[indexPath.row]

        }

        cell.textLabel?.text = contact.value(forKey:"name") as? String

        }
        return cell
    }


    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, commit editingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        if editingStyle == .delete {

            do {

                let contact = contacts[indexPath.row]
                delete(contact, at: indexPath)
                fetch()
                tableView.reloadData()


            } catch let error as NSError {
                print("Could not save. \(error), \(error.userInfo)")
            }
        }
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, canEditRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> Bool {
        // Return false if you do not want the specified item to be editable.
        return true
    }


    @IBAction func unwindToContactList(segue: UIStoryboardSegue) {
        if let viewController = segue.source as? AddContactViewController {
            guard let name: String = viewController.nameTextField.text, let phoneNumber: String = viewController.phoneNumberTextField.text, let dataUltimei: String = viewController.tabel.text else { return }
            if name != "" && phoneNumber != "" {
                if let indexPath = viewController.indexPathForContact {
                    update(indexPath: indexPath, name: name, phoneNumber: phoneNumber, dataUltimei: dataUltimei)
                } else {
                    save(name:name, phoneNumber:phoneNumber, dataUltimei:dataUltimei)
                }
            }
            tableView.reloadData()
        } else if let viewController = segue.source as? ContactDetailViewController {
            if viewController.isDeleted {
                guard let indexPath: IndexPath = viewController.indexPath else { return }
                let contact = contacts[indexPath.row]
                delete(contact, at: indexPath)
                tableView.reloadData()
            }
        }
    }

    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        if segue.identifier == "contactDetailSegue" {
            guard let navViewController = segue.destination as? UINavigationController else { return }
            guard let viewController = navViewController.topViewController as? ContactDetailViewController else { return }
            guard let indexPath = tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow else { return }
            let contact = contacts[indexPath.row]
            viewController.contact = contact
            viewController.indexPath = indexPath
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Hi, welcome to SO. Please add details about what not working means. You may also want to refer to [how to create a minimal, verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) for better results using this site. Good luck!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add the below function:

```
func searchBar(_ searchBar: UISearchBar, textDidChange searchText: String) {
    if !searchText.isEmpty {
        var predicate: NSPredicate = NSPredicate()
        predicate = NSPredicate(format: "name contains[c] '\(searchText)'")
        guard let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as? AppDelegate else { return }
        let managedObjectContext = appDelegate.persistentContainer.viewContext
        let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest<NSFetchRequestResult>(entityName:"Contact")
        fetchRequest.predicate = predicate
        do {
            contacts = try managedObjectContext.fetch(fetchRequest) as! [NSManagedObject]
        } catch let error as NSError {
            print("Could not fetch. \(error)")
        }
    } 
    tableView.reloadData()
}
```

Add UISearchBarDelegate and UISearchDisplayDelegate like below :

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, UISearchBarDelegate, UISearchDisplayDelegate
```

And add the searchBar delegate in viewDidLoad :

```
searchBar.delegate=self
```

Comment: Thank you very much! I did what you said and it did't crash but when I type into the search bar it displays nothing

Comment: May be you are searching for the name which is not exists in it. Please check.

Comment: Yes, I was searching for the contacts name. What should I add to that function to work?

Comment: This is what i want to search by: cell.textLabel?.text = contact.value(forKey:"name") as? String

Comment: Updated the answer. Please check.

Comment: No, same as before, it doesn't display an error but nothing shows up when I type. But I think we should use something like "filteredData" and connect it to the tableview :-?

Comment: Not required. You are assigning fetch value to "contacts" and populating table data using that in tableview delegate. I added this line 'fetchRequest.predicate = predicate'. Did you added it to your code.

Comment: yes, and when I start typing into the bar it says: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException

Comment: Can you please share the code where it is crashing.

Comment: Give me your email please and I will share you the whole project

Comment: Fixed the crash and replied to your email, it has "containscontains[c]" @ line 190 which causing the crash. it should be only one "contains[c]".

Answer (score 1):

To add to the great answer of @ViniApp

In today's Swift you might have something like

```
var searchLetters: String = "" {
    didSet {
        runCoreDataFetchRequest()
        reloadData()
    }
}
```

so, whenever that is changed,

```
override var theFetchRequest: NSFetchRequest<NSFetchRequestResult> {
    let r = NSFetchRequest<NSFetchRequestResult>(entityName: relevantEntityName)

    let s = NSSortDescriptor(key: "id", ascending: false) // for example
    r.sortDescriptors = [s]

    if searchLetters != "" {
        let p = NSPredicate(format: "firstname contains[c] %@", searchLetters)
        r.predicate = p
    }

    return r
}
```

Note that "firstname" in the example above is literally just the name of your actual field in your actual Core Data entity one which you wish to search, so obviously use an actual field name from your actual project, instead of "firstname".

Notice the fetch request is built using `searchLetters`

Then, the core of your core data call would be:

```
var frc: NSFetchedResultsController<NSFetchRequestResult>!

func runCoreDataFetchRequest() {
    frc = NSFetchedResultsController(
        fetchRequest: theFetchRequest,
        managedObjectContext: core.container.viewContext,
        sectionNameKeyPath: nil,
        cacheName: nil)
    frc.delegate = self

    do {
        try frc.performFetch()
    } catch {
        fatalError("frc fetch fail \(error)")
    }
}
```

Notice it uses `theFetchRequest`, whatever value that is at the moment.

So in short runCoreDataFetchRequest runs a `performFetch` for you.

Finally don't forget that after running a fetch, you just reload the table or collection view:

So notice

```
var searchLetters: String = "" {
    didSet {
        runCoreDataFetchRequest()
        reloadData()
    }
}
```

setting the `searchLetters` in fact does the whole thing!